# regex to capture just filename (no url path, no extension)

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, I can use this regex `([^\/]+)(\.[^\.\/]+)$` to capture just the filename in a URL. It works well in the following cases:

```
http://a.com/b/file.name.ext
http://a.com/b/file.name.ext#hash
http://a.com/b/file.name.ext?query
```

However it fails to match if there is no extension:

No match

```
http://a.com/b/filename
http://a.com/b/filename#hash
http://a.com/b/filename?query
```

This is normal. The second capturing group expects there to be a `.ext` chunk at the end.

If I make the second capturing group optional...

```
`([^\/]+)(\.[^\.\/]+)?$`
```

... then the first capturing group becomes greedy, and includes the `.ext` ending, which I don't want. How is the regex engine thinking about the optional second group? How can I make the existence of an extension optional?

---

NOTE: This regex is not intended for use with URLs with the following structure:

```
http://a.com/b/filename?query=a.b
http://a.com/b/filename.ext?query=a.b
```

In my case, dots will never appear later in the the URL.

Comment: Just don't match dots in the first greedy group: `([^\/.]+)`

Comment: @JoSo: There may be dots inside the file name. I've edited my question to make this clear.

Comment: Then if  you want pure regex I think you need alternative  groups: `([^\/.]+)$|([^\/]+)(\.[^\/.]+)$` and identify groups 1 and 2. Group 3 is the optional extension.

Comment: @JoSo Of course! (I was trying alternatives, but I didn't think of making an alternative for the complete expression.)  `([^\/.]+)$|([^\/]+)(\.[^\/.]+)$` works for me (with a `$` after the the first alternative. If you would like to give that as an answer, I can give you points for it.

Comment: how about you `.split('.')[0]` and then match?

Comment: In `http://a.com/b/filen.ame`, there's noway to tell whether `ame` is a part of the name or an extension !! (unless you give a list of allowed extensions)

Comment: @Enissay You are right. My assumption is that if there are any dots in the file name, then the last one is an extension. But that might not be the case for others who have a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want pure regex (= nice and clean regular language expression from theoretical computer science, plus capturing groups), then you can do it with alternative groups:

```
([^\/.]+)$|([^\/]+)(\.[^\/.]+)$
```

and identify groups 1 and 2. Group 3 is the optional extension.

Another possibility:

```
([^\/.]+)(([^\/]*)(\.[^\/.]+))?$
```

Here you'd use group 4 as the extension, and the concatenation of groups 1 and 3 as the filename. Group 2 is only used to make the compound of 3 and 4 optional.

Comment: Your second proposition also captures any query or hash sections if there is no extension. See here: https://regex101.com/r/hB9dK8/1

Comment: @JamesNewton All regexen on this page capture those, so far. But you can avoid that by including `#` and `?` in all negated groups, and not matching the end-of-input with `$`. Or simpler, just strip the queries and hashes beforehand

Answer (score 1):

Tested with:

```
http://a.com/b/file.name.ext
http://a.com/b/filename
http://a.com/b/filename#hash
http://a.com/b/filename?query
```

```js
var file = "http://a.com/b/filename#hash";
function getFileName(url) {
    var index = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    var filenameWithExtension = url.substr(index);
    var filename = filenameWithExtension.split(".")[0]; 
    filename = filename.replace(/(#|\?).*?$/, "");
    return filename;                                   
}

alert(getFileName(file));
//filename
```

---

References:

[lastindexof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastindexof)

[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

[substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

[replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)